# P/Invoking a defined-length C char* array in a struct

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c

I've looked for a while, but found no article that provides an answer to this so hopefully it isn't a duplicate.

I've been doing some P/Invoking with a struct, which is nice and everything, but then I saw this:

`char* infoString[SIDTUNE_MAX_CREDIT_STRINGS];`

where SIDTUNE_MAX_CREDIT_STRINGS is defined as 10.

So inlining everything, the struct member is defined as:

`char* infoString[10]`

Now this is where it gets slightly different from the other issues I've looked through to try and solve this.

The char* array contains pointers to other C strings.

In this specific case, only 3 of the indexes are used while the rest are reserved. The indexes are as follows:

- infoString[0] = Song title
- infoString[1] = Artist name
- infoString[2] = Copyright/Publisher.

How would I P/Invoke this in a way I can access each of those strings from C#? Making C++ functions that return each one individually is not an option.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985067/marshalling-a-struct-containing-string

Comment: That question only provides an answer on how to handle an actual string in C (ie, a char array), not on how to P/Invoke an array of pointers that point to C strings.

Comment: oops... didn't notice that.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the function something like `GetSongInfo(int songID, LPInfostring songinfo)`, you can define the `struct` as having an array of `IntPtr`.  However, you will have to watch out for memory leaks as the calling function may expect you to free the memory allocated for the strings returned.

target.h:

```
typedef struct SongInfo
{
    char* infoString[10];
} *LPSongInfo;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetSongInfo(int songID, LPSongInfo info);
```

target.c:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetSongInfo(int songID, LPSongInfo demo)
{
    demo->infoString[0] = "Hello world";
    demo->infoString[1] = "Hello 1";
    demo->infoString[2] = "Hello 2";

    return TRUE;
}
```

P/Invoke Signature:

```
[DllImport("PInvokeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int GetSongInfo(int songID, out SongInfo ts);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SongInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public IntPtr[] infoString;
};
```

Example Use:

```
SongInfo siStruct;
var num2 = GetSongInfo(101, out siStruct);

// copy the results to managed memory
var results = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (siStruct.infoString[i] != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // if these were Unicode strings, this would change to PtrToSTringUni
        results[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(siStruct.infoString[i]);
    }
}

// results now holds the .Net strings
// if there is an expectation of the caller to free the struct 
// strings, that should happen now
```

As an alternative for functions which do not allocate memory, you can use a struct like the following to marshal the strings automatically.  However, it will free the unmanaged memory unconditionally, which may or may not be desirable.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SongInfo2
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 10)]
    public string[] infoString;
};
```