# C# calling a function from unmanaged c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged

I have this panini scanner api (written in c++ i suppose) which i want to call from c# application.
PS: I dont have the implementation of this DLL, only the header and the dll file.
the function declaration from VApiInterface.h file is

```
typedef DWORD     ERR_CODE;
typedef ERR_CODE  VAPI_RET_TYPE;


typedef struct _DeviceListStruct
{
  DWORD DeviceType;
  char  DeviceSerialNumber[MVX_SN_SIZE];
  DWORD DeviceID;
  DWORD InternalDeviceID;
  BOOL  Connected;
}DEVICELISTSTRUCT,* PDEVICELISTSTRUCT;

// Tag for VISION API function declaration
#define VISION_API_DECL           __declspec(dllexport)

// VISION API function tag
#define VISION_API                WINAPI
VISION_API_DECL VAPI_RET_TYPE VISION_API VApiGetDeviceList(PDEVICELISTSTRUCT pDevList, DWORD Length, DWORD *DetectedDevices);
```

and i'm trying to call this function from c# like this

```
public class VisionAPI
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct _DeviceListStruct
    {
        public uint DeviceType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string DeviceSerialNumber;
        public uint DeviceID;
        public uint InternalDeviceID;
        public bool Connected;
    }
    [DllImport("VisionAPI.dll", EntryPoint = "VApiGetDeviceList")]
    public static extern uint VApiGetDeviceList(ref _DeviceListStruct d,uint len,ref uint devices);
}


////////////
//the call

VisionAPI._DeviceListStruct d = new VisionAPI._DeviceListStruct() ;
VisionAPI.VApiGetDeviceList(ref d, 0, 0);
```

and I m getting this error

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'VApiGetDeviceList' in DLL 'VisionAPI.dll'.
```

as a java backend developer I'm really out of my element here and I have absolutely no Idea what I'm doing wrong.
plz help.

Comment: Did you check the map file?  The method need to be in the map for c# to see the entry point.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=vs-2019

Comment: map file? i dont know where to find it. but in the declaration of the function __declspec(dllexport) is specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find an entry point when calling C++ dll in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109590/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-when-calling-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You structure declaration is wrong too. The string needs a [proper `MarshalAs` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985651/11683).

Comment: @GSerg all I have is the .h file, the dll is already build,so i dont know if the implementation has the `extern`  in it.
and i added `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 11)]` to the string variable in the struct definition and it doesn't work

Comment: Then grab an exe viewer and see what name this function actually has in the dll. Also the last parameter is `ref uint devices` or `out uint devices`.

Comment: @GSerg I already did that and the function name is `unsigned long __stdcall VApiGetDeviceList(struct _DeviceListStruct *,unsigned long,unsigned long *) 0x1000b860 0x0000b860 87 (0x57) VisionAPI.dll`

Comment: Then you are using a wrong VisionAPI.dll.

Comment: @GSerg I have a sample project in visual c++ that is using the same DLL, is there any chance that the dll can be used in a cpp project and not in c#?

Comment: Provided that it has that exported function, no.